# How to get device IMEI for all APIs?

Tags: android, deprecated

Here's my getIMEI function:

```
public static String getIMEI(Context c){
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) c
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
}
```

The problem is that for all devices with API >= 26 the

> getDeviceId()

method is deprecated. My question is how do I make my function to work for all APIs. Is there an alternative to getDeviceId() ?

Comment: What do you need the device ID for? The API was deprecated for a reason.

Comment: I need the device ID as part of the Primary Key in my 'devices' table.